# What do the different colours of fumes over cities mean

Tags: rome-2-total-war

As you can see in the screenshot below (full size [here](http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/577873793396339946/455E108301C369E62EF8CEADE862928E25D48206/)) my own settlement (Moridunon) has white "fumes", whereas my ally's city (Iska) has green ones. **But** my enemy's settlement (Eblana, far left) doesn't have any fumes - nor do all of my own cities.

So at first I thought it had something to do with population growth, but that seems unlikely. Something to do with diplomacy seems unlikely as well, because then I would expect my enemy's city to be red.

[image: Coloured fumes]

Comment: It means you are building in that spot or upgrading the spot in the city, i don't know about the color of the smoke since i've never even noticed a difference in color :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **white** fumes happen when a city is **building or upgrading** a building. The **green** sickly fumes mean that the city has been hit by a **plague**. Looking at your picture it looks like the fumes are comming from the army so this would mean that it is actually the army that has been hit by the plague and not the city itself.